# Sudden missing icon for Google Apps Marketplace Listing/Universal Navigation Extension

Tags: google-apps-marketplace, google-developers-console

We've had our application published in GAM for many years, and suddenly in the past two months we had some users report that our icon was missing.

It's missing from the Marketplace listing ( https://apps.google.com/marketplace/app/flkehfnoahcggpdmnpgjikhicghchnii?hl=en ) as well as the [Universal Navigation Extension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeRPh.png).

I've tried republishing the app through the Chrome Webstore area for GAM, reuploading the images there, and have also reuploaded the images for 96x and 48x in console.developers.google.com/apis/api/appsmarket_component/googleapps_sdk and republished - all to no success.

We did the 96x and 48x because the editor said those were required for Universal Navigation

Any guidance or tips on how we can fix this missing image?